# Are regions a factor in downloading current Ethereum blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

We are currently having some problems syncing our nodes. Our server is located at the Asia Pacific region. Earlier our servers where in Azure and we don't have any troubles syncing. It has been 3 weeks that we are still behind for about an average of 70 to 100 blocks, in addition we are capped at 10mbps and our hard disk is SSD (1TB) but were not seeing any signs of completing the sync anytime soon. We are using geth's latest version 1.8.23. The parameters are:

```
geth.exe --syncmode "fast" --networkid 1 --datadir=<location> --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal,net,miner,admin,debug,txpool" --cache=1024 --maxpeers 100
```

Have anyone encountered this issue specifically users in Asia Pacific? Is there anything that we can do to speed up the syncing?

Thanks in advance!